# Changing writer prefix when (is => “rwp”)

Tags: perl, moo, moops

If I want to change write protected attribute ie.

```
use Moops;

class foo {
  has attr => (is => "rwp");
}
```

one have to use `_set_attr()`.

Is it possible to change that to `_attr()` without using explicit `writer`?

Tried [`use MooseX::::AttributeShortcuts -writer_prefix => 'prefix';`](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::AttributeShortcuts#writer_prefix) but it did not work.

Comment: You need to give us a lot more information here. Which modules are you using to get the current behaviour?

Comment: @DaveCross it's already tagged with `Moops`; https://metacpan.org/release/Moops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, you need to do that yourself by setting the `writer`.

TLDR: At the bottom is a monkey-patch to do it anyway.

---

The [Moops docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) say (emphasys mine):

> Moops uses MooseX::MungeHas in your classes so that the has keyword
>   supports some **Moo-specific features**, even when you're using Moose or
>   Mouse. **Specifically, it supports `is => 'rwp'`**, `is => 'lazy'`, `builder =>
>   1`, `clearer => 1`, `predicate => 1`, and `trigger => 1`.

Now let's go look at [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo#has). In the `has` section of the doc, it says (emphasys mine):

> `rwp` stands for "read-write protected" and generates a reader like `ro`,
>   but also sets writer to `_set_${attribute_name}` for attributes that are
>   designed to be written from inside of the class, but read-only from
>   outside. This feature comes from MooseX::AttributeShortcuts.

Ok, on to [MooseX::AttributeShortcuts](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::AttributeShortcuts#is-rwp):

> Specifying is => 'rwp' will cause the following options to be set:
>
> ```
> is     => 'ro'
> writer => "_set_$name"
> ```

However, this is just where it was inspired. It is actually implemented in Moo in [Method::Generate::Accessor](https://metacpan.org/source/HAARG/Moo-2.000002/lib/Method/Generate/Accessor.pm#L47)<sup>1</sup>.

> ```
>   } elsif ($is eq 'rwp') {
>     $spec->{reader} = $name unless exists $spec->{reader};
>     $spec->{writer} = "_set_${name}" unless exists $spec->{writer};
>   } elsif ($is ne 'bare') {
> ```

And even more actually, that is also not where it is done in Moops. In fact, that happens in [MooseX::MungeHas](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/MooseX-MungeHas-0.007/lib/MooseX/MungeHas.pm#L142), which Moops uses, but only if the caller is not Moo:

> ```
>             push @code, '  if ($_{is} eq q(rwp)) {';
>             push @code, '    $_{is}     = "ro";';
>             push @code, '    $_{writer} = "_set_$_" unless exists($_{writer});';
>             push @code, '  }';
> ```

Looks pretty clear. It's in generated code. The below solution might work if it uses only Moo, but I don't know how to force that.

---

You are indeed able to change that **in Moo** by hooking into Moo's Method::Generate::Accessor using Class::Method::Modifiers and adding a bit of logic in an `around` modifier to `generate_method`. This <strike>does not work</strike> works for Moops as long as there is no Moose-stuff involved.

```
use Moops;

BEGIN {
  require Method::Generate::Accessor; # so it's in %INC;
  require Class::Method::Modifiers;
  Class::Method::Modifiers::around( 'Method::Generate::Accessor::generate_method' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;

    #      0      1      2      3      4
    #  my ($self, $into, $name, $spec, $quote_opts) = @_;

    if ($_[3]->{is} eq 'rwp') {
      $_[3]->{writer} = "_explicitly_set_$_[2]" unless exists $_[3]->{reader};
    }

    $orig->(@_);
  });
}

class Foo {
    has attr => ( is => "rwp" );
}

use Data::Printer;

my $foo = Foo->new( attr => 1 );
p $foo;
```

**Output**:

```
Foo  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : attr, new
    private methods (1) : _explicitly_set_attr
    internals: {
        attr   1
    }
}
```

---

<sub>1) I found that using [grep.cpan.me](http://grep.cpan.me/?q=dist%3A%22Moo%22%20rwp).</sub>

Comment: @Сухой27 I thought that was strange, too, but the Moo docs say it comes from MooseX::AttributeShortcuts. My second quote is from Moo. It might be they just mean that the idea was _taken_ from there.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't up-vote more than once. So, it is hardcoded.. `:)`

Comment: @Сухой27  We can probably overwrite it. I'm trying.

Comment: @Сухой27 I was wrong. Edited the answer. In fact it's in MooseX::MungeHas. There it generated code. Not sure how to hook into that to overwrite. The Moo stuff is fun, but not helpful if you are using Moops I'm afraid. I suggest you go to #moose and ask Toby.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90539/discussion-between-simbabque-and-27).